# How do I turn off vhdl-mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am learning emacs at the moment and tried to write an easy vhdl program for testing. I can see that the vhdl-mode might be an interesting feature, but I would like to know how I can turn it off for the moment and how I can reactivate it later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command *M-x fundamental-mode*, that is:

- Press (and hold) the *meta* key (which is usually the *Alt* key)
- Press *x*

This will take the cursor into the echo area at the bottom of the screen/frame. Type *fundamental-mode* and press *return*.

To disable VHDL mode permanently, you will have to change the file-extension mapping used by emacs to associate a file's extension with a particular major mode. You can do this by writing a custom *.emacs* configuration file. Look for *auto-mode-alist* in the emacs manual:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (remove (rassoc 'vhdl-mode auto-mode-alist) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: Thank you! To get back into vhdl-mode, just type "M-x vhdl-mode".

Answer (score 1):

Change to some other mode, e.g.

```
M-x fundamental-mode RET
```

or

```
M-x indented-text-mode RET
```

re-enable it by entering

```
M-x vhdl-mode RET
```