# How to disable Verilog mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, proof-general

I'm trying to use coq with ProofGeneral, but the built-in Verilog mode shadows `*.v` filetype recognition. Can I somehow disable it and let ProofGeneral remap them to its coq mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to have to override the binding in auto-mode-alist in your .emacs or whatnot.

This SO post does something similar with VHDL:

[How do I turn off vhdl-mode in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361785/how-do-i-turn-off-vhdl-mode-in-emacs)

Also, I googled for "auto-mode-alist remove" and found [this link](http://www.aerojockey.com/files/emacs.txt). Copy/Pasting the important bit:

```lisp
;; Remove all annoying modes from auto mode lists

(defun replace-alist-mode (alist oldmode newmode)
  (dolist (aitem alist)
    (if (eq (cdr aitem) oldmode)
    (setcdr aitem newmode))))

;; not sure what mode you want here. You could default to 'fundamental-mode
(replace-alist-mode auto-mode-alist 'verilog-mode 'proof-general-mode)
```

Comment: Just found this too, but I'll accept yours for verbosity and the reference ;).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ProofGeneral, but if I understand your question correctly, you need to modify the `auto-mode-alist` variable to associate the correct major with files with the `.v` extension. So, you need to add something like this to your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.v$" . proof-general-coq-mode))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line worked:

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist (remove (rassoc 'verilog-mode auto-mode-alist) auto-mode-alist))
```

Answer (score 1):

That might be an XY-problem.

I got the same problem today, firstly, I tried the same thing as you, I add following into my `~/.spacemacs` under `dotspacemacs/user-init`:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (remove (rassoc 'verilog-mode auto-mode-alist) auto-mode-alist))
```

And then the mode becomes fundamental, and then I realized that the real reason is that the spacemacs **coq layer isn't installed** automatically, and you need a lot of effort to install it and it's dependencies well.

Following is my summarize about the installation steps after I successfully run Coq up on Emacs:  https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/68e5e38496b79790e70d82814bdfc69a

Hope this helpful :)